# Agrupar valores de un dataframe en rangos

Tags: r

Me gustaría agrupar una tabla como esta:

df:

```
      lib           sstart    
      PV002          256
      PV002          256
      PV002          390
      PV002          834
      PV003          626
      PV003          834
      PV003          1075
      PV004          116
      PV004          320
      PV005          400
```

En una tabla como esta:

```
      lib          sstart_range
     PV002          [256-834]
     PV003          [626-1075]
     PV004          [116-320]
     PV005          [400]
```

He probado esta función pero no obtengo resultados:

```
Record_DNAJ<-df%>% 
group_by(lib, sstart) %>% 
 summarize(sstart_range = paste(range(sstart)))
```

¿Cuál es mi fallo?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lo que estas buscando: pegar los dos elementos del vector que te retorna `range()` y retornar un solo dato a `summarize()` y no dos, tienes que usar el parámetro `collapse`:

```
summarize(sstart_range = paste(range(sstart), collapse="-"))
```

El valor es la cadena con las que vas a separar cada valor del rango.

Comment: Gracias Patricio, el código hace su función.